# Handling "chain questions"

Tags: discussion

I just wrote an answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43880083/3000206) . It solved their original problem. Great.

Then they changed the question by updating the code, invalidating my answer. We're now having a discussion in comments regarding how to define different functions in Haskell.

How should this be handled? If the first question could basically be chalked up to a typo, should it be closed as "can no longer be reproduced"? Should I be modifying my already upvoted question to accommodate the change? I don't want to be rude to them, but the evolution of the question isn't really appropriate for the site.

Comment: Yeah, that's annoying and it's not ok to change a question out from under answers.  These are sometimes called "chameleon questions", and your problem is not new.  Good luck!

Comment: By the way, this is my first use of the dupe-hammer.  If you disagree that it's a dupe, please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Then they changed the question by updating the code, invalidating my answer.

That's inacceptable and unwanted behavior. Those edits should be rolled back (leaving the specific reason, that already existing answers are invalidated).

Recommend the OP to ask another question about the changed code.

---

BTW, such behavior indicates a misconception of the OP, that a specific SE site is meant as their *"personal helpdesk"*, and kinda help vampirism.
Most probably these kind of questions are duplicates or off-topic otherwise at all.